# How do I delete a user's new message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm pretty trash at coding so I need a little bit of help. I'm trying to code my discord bot to delete someone's messages for one minute after they click a react emoji. It sounds simple but for my tiny pea brain, it's not. This is what I have got so far. It deletes all messages from different users and guilds it's in, forever. I want it so it only delete messages in one channel for one minute.

```
  client.once('message', async userMessage => {
    if (userMessage.content.startsWith('')) 
      {
         botMessage = await userMessage.channel.send('Who here likes goats?')
            await botMessage.react("") 
            await botMessage.react("") 
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return (
                  ["", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === userMessage.author.id
                );
         };
              botMessage
              .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ["time"] })
              .then((collected) => {
                const reaction = collected.first();
        
                if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
                userMessage.channel.send(`${userMessage.author}, how dare you. I guess no on here likes me. Hmmm, because of that I shall now eat all your messages! BAAAAAHAHAHHAHAHA!`)
                setTimeout(() => {
                  client.on("message", async msg => {
                    if (author.msg.content.startsWith("")) {
                        userMessage.channel = await msg.delete();
                    }
                });
                }, 2000);
                } else {
                  userMessage.reply("Thanks!");
                }
              })
              .catch((_collected) => {
                userMessage.channel.send("Hehe")
              });
      }
  });
```

Btw, the code is in discord.js!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this chunk of code

```js
setTimeout(() => {
   client.on("message", async msg => {
      if (author.msg.content.startsWith("")) {
         userMessage.channel = await msg.delete();
      }
   });
}, 2000);
```

This is not how you use events.

A) Your message event is *nested* within another which could cause memory leaks.

B) To get the content you need to use `msg.content`, `author.msg` Is not a thing.

C) I assume your intention here: `msg.content.startsWith("")` is to always fire the if statement, in that case why not do `if (true)`.

---

Here's how I would do it:

Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in the namespace which will hold id's of users who's messages should be deleted

```js
const toDelete = new Set();
```

If they react with a  add them to the set.

```js
if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
   userMessage.channel.send('Your message here');

   if (!toDelete.has(userMessage.author.id)) {
      toDelete.add(userMessage.author.id);
   }
}
```

On each message event check if the author of the message has their id in the set, If so delete their message

```js
client.once('message', async userMessage => {
    if (toDelete.has(userMessage.author.id)) {
       return userMessage.delete()
          .catch(console.error);
    }

    if (userMessage.content.startsWith('')) {
       // Rest of your code
```

Comment: Everything works except this part of the code.

              } else {
                userMessage.reply("Thanks!");
              }
            })
            .catch((_collected) => {
              userMessage.channel.send("Hehe")
            });
    }
});

How do you get a response from the other reaction? I'm sorry if I'm a pain in the butt

Comment: Any reaction that matches the given filter will be passed onto the `.then()` callback